# Could not find builder-2.1.2 in any of the sources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundle, builder

I'm following the [Getting Started with Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) guide, but I ran into a problem:

```
bash-4.1$ bundle install
Using rake (0.8.7) 
Using abstract (1.0.0) 
Using activesupport (3.0.3) 
Using builder (2.1.2) 
Using i18n (0.5.0) 
Using activemodel (3.0.3) 
Using erubis (2.6.6) 
Using rack (1.2.1) 
Using rack-mount (0.6.13) 
Using rack-test (0.5.7) 
Using tzinfo (0.3.24) 
Using actionpack (3.0.3) 
Using mime-types (1.16) 
Using polyglot (0.3.1) 
Using treetop (1.4.9) 
Using mail (2.2.14) 
Using actionmailer (3.0.3) 
Using arel (2.0.7) 
Using activerecord (3.0.3) 
Using activeresource (3.0.3) 
Using bundler (1.0.7) 
Using thor (0.14.6) 
Using railties (3.0.3) 
Using rails (3.0.3) 
Using sqlite3-ruby (1.3.2) 
Your bundle is complete! Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
bash-4.1$ rake db:create
(in /Users/user/Documents/blog)
Could not find builder-2.1.2 in any of the sources
Try running `bundle install`.
bash-4.1$ bundle show builder
/Users/user/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/builder-2.1.2
```

I also tried installing Builder as a RubyGem, but that didn't change a thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try running it through `bundle exec` to make sure all of the gems specified in your Gemfile are available at their correct versions: `bundle exec rake db:create`

Comment: How can I install an older version of a gem?

Comment: In your Gemfile:
`gem 'foo', '1.2.3'`

Answer (score 0):

You can verify the installed gem is visible to bundle like this:

```
bundle show builder

/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/builder-2.1.2
```

I have the same problem though, `bundle exec rake` still fails to see the installed gem.

Comment: Paul, what part of the question do you consider this to an answer to?  It seems like you are just saying that have the same problem, which would be more appropriate as a comment on the question.

Answer (score 0):

My version of rake (installed at /usr/bin/rake) was pointing at an old version of Ruby 1.8.

Modify the first line of rake to point at the correct version of Ruby. You can also clear out the bundle cache under the 'vendor' directory or move bundle to another local directory:

> bundle install --path gems

On the command line, locate your default 'ruby' and 'rake' commands and check the version of Ruby:

> which ruby
>
> which rake
>
> ruby -v

In /usr/bin/rake (line #1):

> #!/opt/local/bin/ruby